# Adding class to nth-child range in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class to nth-child range with this code, which is not working:

```
$('.station li:nth-child(' + strno + '):nth-child(' + endno + ')').attr('class', 'current');
```

If I try to change the class for a specific element using this code then it does work:

```
$('.station li:nth-child(' + strno + ')').attr('class', 'current');
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gt()` and `lt()` selector to select a range of child like following.

```js
var strno = 1, endno = 3; // 0 based index
$('.station li:gt(' + (strno - 1) + '):lt(' + (endno - strno + 1) + ')').addClass('current');
```

```css
.current {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="station">
    <li>Item 0</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a selector such as

```
.station li:nth-child(2):nth-child(10)
```

With the expectation that that sets up a *range* of `nth-child` elements - it doesn't, you're mistaken.

This sets up a kind of "and" logic, where you're telling the selector engine to find elements which are both 2nd **and** 10th child. Clearly an element cannot be both.

I suggest you use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select only those elements you're interested in from the entire set of `.station li` elements.

```js
$('.station li').filter(function (e){
  var idx = $(this).index();
  return idx>=1 && idx<4;
}).css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="station">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```